# Maximum nodes in AVL tree with distinct positive integers

Tags: number-theory, graph-theory, algorithms, recurrence-relations, trees

Assuming that all keys in an AVL tree are distinct positive integers. Suppose that the root node of an AVL tree T holds the key N. What can be estimated largest possible number of nodes in T ?

We know that AVL tree follow following properties :

```
Self balancing Binary Search Tree.
The heights of the two child subtrees of any node differ by at most one;
If at any time they differ by more than one, rebalancing is done to restore this property.
```

I know that minimum number of nodes in AVL tree is given by this recursion :

S(h) = S(h-1) + S(h-2) + 1.

Comment: Are all the keys nonnegative?

Comment: @Ken Distinct positive integers . I think it make things clear enough

Comment: Sorry, read too quickly.

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned for different positive integers,so I am assuming numbers will be ***1 to N***,for some positive integer ***N>=2***::
Answer is::
***N-1+2^{[log(N-1)]+2}*** ,
where in above formula,
**N=ROOT KEY**

log **x**= logarithmic value of **x** to base **2**
**[ x]**=***Floor*** of **x** i.e. highest integer less than or equal to **x** and

**x^y**= **x** raise to power of **y**.

***Explanation***:: As AVL Tree with root N will contain exactly **N-1** nodes in it's left subtree with height **log(N-1)** and it's left subtree will be balanced in itself with height balance property of AVL Tree.
Let us say the height of left subtree be **h** ::
So , it's right subtree can be of **h+1**height and hence can contain at max **-1+ 2^{h+1+1}** nodes,
hence the answer will be left subtree nodes +1+right subtree nodes.
Now left subtree nodes=**N-1**,so
MAXIMUM NO. OF NODES IN AVL TREE WITH ROOT NODE N WILL BE::
**N-1+2^{[log(N-1)]+2}**.
NOTE :: Above formula is valid only for **N>=2 BUT** FOR **N=1**, no. Of nodes will be **2**.